# How to add owners as members to a studio group when its created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now whenever i create a studio the current user is made the owner of the studio but he is not made a member of it. What would be the way of doing that?

Controllers:

```
class StudiosController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @studio = Studio.new(studio_params)
    @studio.owner = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @studio.save
        format.html { redirect_to @studio, notice: 'Studio was successfully created.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def members
    @members = studio.memberships

    @membership = Membership.new
  end
end

class MembershipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @membership = studio.memberships.create membership_params

    redirect_to members_studio_path(@studio)
  end
end
```

Models:

```
class Studio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :studio
  belongs_to :user

  delegate :email, to: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :studios, through: :memberships
  has_many :created_studios, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: "Studio"
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :studios do
  member do
    get :members
  end

  resources :memberships, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the current_user to the `users` association right after making them the owner:

```
def create
  @studio = Studio.new(studio_params)
  @studio.owner = current_user
  @studio.users << current_user

  ...

end
```

For clarity you may want to change the association name to `:members`:

```
has_many :members, through: :memberships, source: :user
```

Comment: has_many :members, class_name: 'User', through: :memberships <- this returns: Could not find the source association(s) :member or :members in model Membership. If i wanted to do @studio.members << current_user i had to go with this -> has_many :members, through: :memberships, source: :user.